# XSSFDataFormat with format "#%" multiplies by 100 numeric cell value. How to handle it?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use ApachePOI and XSSFWorkbook. I did style for cell with numeric percentage value with next settings:

```java
XSSFCellStyle numericPercentageStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
numericPercentageStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
numericPercentageStyle.setFont(font);
numericPercentageStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat(PERCENTAGE_FORMAT));
```

, where PERCENTAGE_FORMAT is:

```java
private static final String PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = "#%";
```

I also tried to use "0%" and "0.000%", but the value is always multiplied by 100. I would not want to divide the value by 100 before applying the style. I understand that this option is possible, but this is an unnecessary operation.

Comment: If you format 1 as a percentage, it **is** 100%, not 1%, so you'll have to divide them.

Comment: @Rory, yeah, I understand this logic. But is there really no other solution for this format?

Comment: Unfortunately this is how `Excel` works. The percent format is more than only a number format as it not only decorates the number but also interprets it. A numeric value of 1 is 100%, 0.5 is 50%. That's why a numeric value of 10 is 1000%.

Comment: @AxelRichter, understood, thank you very much!
Well, I'll divide by 100 :(

Comment: You *could* use a format of `"0\%"` but it would be a **really** bad idea...

Comment: @Rary, yes, this style is working correct for me right now. 
What could go wrong?

Comment: @Nikolay Murza: What could go wrong? Well, all calculations using those values. The format `"0\%"` only decorates numbers as if they were percentages. This is not what `Excel`'s percentage format does.